# How could we generate random numbers in CUDA C with different seed on each run?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu

I am working on a stochastic process and I wanted to generate different series if random numbers in CUDA kernel each time I run the program. 
This similar to what we does in C++ by declaring
seed = time(null) 
followed by srand(seed) 
and rand( )

I can pass seeds from host to device via the kernel but
the problem in doing this is I would have to pass an entire array of seeds into the kernel for each thread to have a different random seed each time. Is there a way I could generate random seed / process if / machine time or something like than within the kernel and pass it as a seed?

Comment: what did you have so far as code?

Comment: I am currently using curand_uniform() for random number generation but it calls the same set of random number each time I run it
I can pass seeds from host to device via the kernel but
the problem in doing this is I would have to pass an entire array of seeds into the kernel for each thread to have a different random seed each time. Is there a way I could generate random seed / process if / machine time or something like than within the kernel and pass it as a seed?

Comment: You can use a single master seed and then offset into the sequence according to thread index. Note that simply using different seeds to the same generator is not statistically robust, you should use a single seed and then offset into the sequence to get distinct sub-sequences.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to pass an array of random seeds, but, when you use the cuRAND library, you can properly set the sequence number parameter of `curand_init`. For example [Disclaimer: it is a non-tested function]

```
__global__ void generate_random_numbers(float* numbers, unsigned long seed, int Np) {

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (i < Np) {

        curandState state;

        curand_init(seed, i, 0, &state);

        numbers[i] = curand_uniform(&state);
    }
}
```

You can also avoid passing the seed from outside if you change the `curand_init` instruction to

```
curand_init(clock64(), i, 0, &state);
```

**EDIT**

Following Roger Dahl's comment, I have done a comparison (Kepler K20c) between four different possibilities for the generation of arrays of `131072` elements:

1. Single random number generation: separate kernels for initialization and random number generation;
2. Single random number generation: unique kernel for initialization and random number generation;
3. Multiple random number generation: separate kernels for initialization and random number generation;
4. Multiple random number generation: unique kernel for initialization and random number generation;

Below is the code. The timing for generating has been the following:

1. `861ms`;
2. `852ms`;
3. `866ms`;
4. `2556ms`;

I hope I have correctly understood the performance issue raised by Roger Dahl.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#define DSIZE 8192*16
#define nTPB 256

/***********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECKING */
/***********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line); 
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/*************************/
/* CURAND INITIALIZATION */
/*************************/
__global__ void initCurand(curandState *state, unsigned long seed){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &state[idx]);
}

__global__ void testrand1(curandState *state, float *a){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    a[idx] = curand_uniform(&state[idx]);
}

__global__ void testrand2(unsigned long seed, float *a){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    curandState state;
    curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &state);
    a[idx] = curand_uniform(&state);
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    int n_iter = 20;

    curandState *devState;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&devState, DSIZE*sizeof(curandState)));

    float *d_a;             gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, DSIZE*sizeof(float)));

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<n_iter; i++) {

        initCurand<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(devState, 1);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        testrand1<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(devState, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time for separate kernels:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<n_iter; i++) {

        testrand2<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(1, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time for single kernels:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<n_iter; i++) {

        initCurand<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(devState, 1);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        testrand1<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(devState, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        testrand1<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(devState, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        testrand1<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(devState, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time for separate kernels with multiple random number generation:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<n_iter; i++) {

        testrand2<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(1, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        testrand2<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(1, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        testrand2<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(1, d_a);
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time for single kernels for multiple random number generation:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    getchar();
}
```

**Output on GTX660:**

```
Elapsed time for separate kernels:  1960.3 ms
Elapsed time for single kernels:  1536.9 ms
Elapsed time for separate kernels with multiple random number generation:  1576.0 ms
Elapsed time for single kernels for multiple random number generation:  4612.2 ms
```

**Output on GTX570:**

```
Elapsed time for separate kernels:  957.2 ms 
Elapsed time for single kernels:  947.7 ms 
Elapsed time for separate kernels with multiple random number generation:  964.6 ms 
Elapsed time for single kernels for multiple random number generation:  2839.0 ms
```

Approximately same performance as the K20c.

Comment: There are performance implications to the different ways of handling the prng seeding. From the Performance Notes section in the curand docs: Calls to curand_init() are slower than calls to curand() or curand_uniform(). Large offsets to curand_init() take more time than smaller offsets. It is much faster to save and restore random generator state than to recalculate the starting state repeatedly.

Comment: @RogerDahl I have edited my answer. I hope I have correctly understood the performance issue you have raised.

Comment: Thank you for investigating the performance issues. I think the main takeaway from that note in the docs is that it's probably a good idea to move the seeding of the PRNGs outside of the loop if possible. So, if you're running a simulation where you keep launching a kernel that generates random numbers, you create a kernel that runs  `curand_init()` for each thread and saves the state. You run that kernel only once when the app starts. Then, inside the loop, you just keep restoring and saving the state.

Comment: @RogerDahl Thanks for adding your own results to my own answer. I think that the above results agree with your last comment in that case #3 has remarkably better performance than case #4.

Answer (score 1):

Using a different seed on each run should be straightforward. The exact method will depend on which generator you are using, but if you're using one of the [cuRAND](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html) generators then you can cast your time_t from time(NULL) to a 64-bit integer and pass it in to the seed functions.

If you're calling the generator from your kernel you will need to pass this seed in either as a kernel argument or via a `__device__` variable. You can then use an offset to `curand_init()` or use `skip_ahead()` to get distinct sub-sequences.

If you have a specific generator for which this will not work, please post more information.

Comment: The problem in doing this is I would have to pass an entire array of seeds into the kernel for each thread to have a different random seed each time. Is there a way I could generate random seed / process if / machine time or something like than within the kernel and pass it as a seed?

Comment: No, you can pass in a single seed and then use an offset into the sequence. You should never just use different seeds anyway, that approach is prone to correlation between sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can create more than one global function for random number initialization and generation. or create a loop to go over the global function
example:
for (int rns = 0; rns < 5; rns++) { // too seed 'loop' times

```
    init << < N, 10 >> > (devState, time(0));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_no, N * sizeof(double))); // allocate memory for random numbers on device/GPU
//rndn << < N, 10 >> > (devState, gpu_no);//invoke kernel to launch the random numbers
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(cpu_no, gpu_no, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost))
} cout << "the transition matrix  " << ++generate << " seed generation is:  " << init << endl;
```

This does nt have any noticeable effect on the random number generated. But there is a fear of not being correlated and also lack of convergence in the long run. Why would you like to seed more than once in an iteration anyways.
you can use the library function to generate different types of random number distribution like "curand_uniform" curand_normal, curand_poission and so on.

I don't know if this answers your question.